# How to add random class to link list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following structure.

```
<ul id="dyn_nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The first level of li (ul#dyn_nav>li) should get random classes from given list.

Classes are blue, green, magenta, cyan, red, etc...

I want to make this menu dynamic color not fixed.

Like one can have first menu color green, another have blue. This is just my Idea.

jQuery please.

Comment: lol! This is a Q & A site lol!

Comment: @bolt I dont know how to add random classes. So did not tried yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var classes = ['blue', 'green', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'red'];
    $('ul#dyn_nav>li').each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass(
            classes[Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
    });
});
```

I also added `ul#dyn_nav>li>a { color: inherit; }` to the stylesheet so that the color would affect the link in the `li` and not just the bullet.

Comment: some time classes get repeated :(

Comment: Well, in this case there are six menu items and only five colors, so at least one has to be repeated. If you have at least as many classes as items then you can use the approach of shuffling them into a random order and applying them in turn to the items.

Answer (score 1):

Put your colors into an array, [randomize it](http://javascript.about.com/library/blsort2.htm), and use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) with [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to assign the values.

Answer (score 0):

Dutow is right. @Wazdesign: You can also try this snippet:

```
function rand(){ return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }
    var colors = new Array('blue','yellow','red','green');//you can add more class here
    var init = colors.sort( rand );
    $('ul li').each(function(i,el){ 
     $(el).addClass(init[i]); 
   });
```

Comment: I don't think sort(rand) is a very good idea; depending on the implementation of sort, that could be an infinite loop.